# I have a vendor trying to communicate with my WCF api, and they are receiving an http:500 error, but IIS logging shows no details

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

High Level: I have a web API, built to the specs of a vendor. It passes all tests and even the vendor's "sample" request works perfectly via SOAPUI. However, when their IBM DataPower software tries to send a request, they receive an HTTP:500 error. IIS logging shows the HTTP:500, but no error description and no other info.

I've set the API to capture any error during code execution via a try/catch at the endpoint class that surrounds everything. No logging. I've also tried fiddler, but I've not been able to get this vendor to send me a test request on demand (I get answers like, "we'll send it in about 2 hours"). All I have are IIS logs of the error, the IP address, and timestamp.

Here's the endpoint. All the methods and classes called are working to spec. This code never gets executed when DataPower makes the call.

Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <webServices>

      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpPost" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="10240" maxUrlLength="10240" executionTimeout="1200" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="claims" name="ISO_ClaimsResponse.ClaimsResponse">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="ISO_ClaimsResponse.IClaimsResponse" />
        </service>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="claims">
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Here's the interface/data contract:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace ISO_ClaimsResponse
{    
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")] -- This is intentional and required per the vendor
    public interface IClaimsResponse
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method ="POST", UriTemplate = "xml")]
        [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IClaimsResponse/ProcessResponse", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IClaimsResponse/ProcessResponse")]
        string ProcessResponse(string xml);        
    }    
}
```

And here's the endpoint code, which I've confirmed is never reached when DataPower is making the call:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ISOClaims;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace ISO_ClaimsResponse
{
    public class ClaimsResponse : IClaimsResponse
    {       
        public string ProcessResponse(string xml)
        {  
            LogRequestModel request = new LogRequestModel();

            try
            {
                ClaimInvestigationAddRs receivedObj = LogData.Serialize<ClaimInvestigationAddRs>(xml);
                request.ClaimInvestigationAddRqID = receivedObj.RqUID.Value;
                request.CD_ID = LogData.GetCDID(request.ClaimInvestigationAddRqID);

                Validation validator = new Validation();
                receivedObj.TransactionResponseDt = validator.DTString(receivedObj.TransactionResponseDt);
                request.TransactionRequestDateTime = DateTime.Parse(receivedObj.TransactionResponseDt);
                request.ResponseXML = "SUCCESS";

                Log.ReceivedRequest(request);
                return "SUCCESS";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> additionalDetails = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                additionalDetails.Add("Received XML", xml);

                Log.Error(ex, additionalDetails);
                request.ResponseXML = "INTERNAL ERROR LOGGED" + ex.ToString();
                Log.ReceivedRequest(request);
                return "INTERNAL ERROR LOGGED";
            }

            return "SUCCESS";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the sample SOAP XML I was provided for testing, which works fine. I've obfuscated PII, just in case.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ProcessResponse>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xml xmlns="">
            <![CDATA[
         <ClaimInvestigationAddRs>
            <RqUID>ccbd5f5eb53e4b8d8357f5873c8ec9bb</RqUID>
            <TransactionResponseDt>2019-01-18T11:18:28</TransactionResponseDt>
            <CurCd>US</CurCd>
            <CodeList id="PolicyTypeCdList">
            <CodeListName>PolicyTypeCd</CodeListName>
            <CodeListOwnerCd>ISOUS</CodeListOwnerCd>
            </CodeList>
            <CodeList id="ClaimsPartyRoleCdList">
            <CodeListName>ClaimsPartyRoleCd</CodeListName>
            <CodeListOwnerCd>ISOUS</CodeListOwnerCd>
            </CodeList>
            <MsgStatus>
            <MsgStatusCd>Rejected</MsgStatusCd>
            <MsgErrorCd>DataError</MsgErrorCd>
            <MsgStatusDesc>TEST</MsgStatusDesc>
            </MsgStatus>
            <Policy>
            <PolicyNumber>NGNV0001921-00</PolicyNumber>
            <LOBCd codelistref="PolicyTypeCdList">PAPP</LOBCd>
            <MiscParty id="Reject_MiscParty_1">
            <ItemIdInfo>
            <AgencyId>XXXXXXXXXX</AgencyId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <MiscPartyInfo>
            <MiscPartyRoleCd>CarrierInsurer</MiscPartyRoleCd>
            </MiscPartyInfo>
            </MiscParty>
            </Policy>
            <ClaimsOccurrence id="Reject_ClaimsOccurence_1">
            <ItemIdInfo>
            <InsurerId>XXXXXXXX</InsurerId>
            </ItemIdInfo>
            <LossDt>2018-10-31</LossDt>
            </ClaimsOccurrence>
            <ClaimsParty id="Reject_IP_1">
            <GeneralPartyInfo>
            <NameInfo>
            <PersonName>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <GivenName>John</GivenName>
            </PersonName>
            </NameInfo>
            </GeneralPartyInfo>
            <ClaimsPartyInfo>
            <ClaimsPartyRoleCd codelistref="ClaimsPartyRoleCdList">IN</ClaimsPartyRoleCd>
            </ClaimsPartyInfo>
            </ClaimsParty>
            <ClaimsParty id="Reject_IP_2">
            <GeneralPartyInfo>
            <NameInfo>
            <PersonName>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <GivenName>Jane</GivenName>
            </PersonName>
            </NameInfo>
            </GeneralPartyInfo>
            <ClaimsPartyInfo>
            <ClaimsPartyRoleCd codelistref="ClaimsPartyRoleCdList">CD</ClaimsPartyRoleCd>
            </ClaimsPartyInfo>
            </ClaimsParty>
            </ClaimInvestigationAddRs>]]></xml>
      </ProcessResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'd be happy if I could just get a copy of the actual envelope and body of what they're sending me. The vendor says they don't know how to do it.

What do I want?

1. Easy way to capture the entire request before IIS or WCF rejects it
2. OR Set IIS or WCF to let anything through to my code
3. OR is there something obvious somewhere in the code or settings I'm overlooking?

This is a test environment. I've validated TLS settings and eliminated network connectivity issues as possible problems.

Here is the actual response that our vendor says they are receiving (I've obfuscated the URL somewhat). This matches the IIS log text as well (included after):

```
The Frontside Handler CSUF-DPN120-REJECT-FSH
on Datapower appliance (isoappgwa2)
has been disabled due to the following error
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> --> Message Failed with HTTP Error Response Code 500 or Status Code 15. It was trying to send SOAP response to https://********.com/ISOSvc/ClaimsResponse.svc , SOAP method is ProcessResponse
```

IIS Log:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2019-09-04 00:07:08 172.16.6.40 POST /ISOSvc/ClaimsResponse.svc - 443 - 206.208.170.60 - - 500 19 50 171
```

For validation, the ProcessResponse endpoint is active and works. I can call it via SOAPUI on our internal network, and from my home PC (so public facing).

I've attempted enabling tracing, and did not get a trace file for any of the received requests. I've validated that all users on this test server (including the user that apps run under) have read/write access to the folder. I've validated the port as well.

UPDATE:  I finally got the vendor to tell me something new. Apparently all the calls they were making to me had a common error in the XML (invalid character), which would explain the HTTP:500 error being caught at such a high level, as it would be flagged as invalid SOAP format. I'm hoping that's the root cause, although I'm not sure at this time. I also saw some major non-matching XML tags in the web.config. I'm not sure where or when they appeared, but I fixed them. I'd be more confident that's the issue except that it didn't cause issues in other tests.

Also, I added the endpoint changes in the web.config.

Comment: I can see two possible reasons of the problem, 1. Service endpoint tag is missing in web.config OR 2. Request length could be more than the allowed in web.config (10240)

Comment: enable Tracing and Message logging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging

Comment: I'm going to enable the tracing. I believe I've solved the length issue. That came up during initial development. I'm hoping the tracing provides additional insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Service configuration is missing in web.config. Try the following if it works.

In web.config, add this inside system.serviceModel tag before behaviors tag:

```
<services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="claims" name="ISO_ClaimsResponse.ClaimsResponse">
   <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
   contract="ISO_ClaimsResponse.IClaimsResponse" />
   </service>
<services>
```

and add the name attribute to behavior tag to make it look like:

```
<behavior name="claims">
```

Comment: I like the response, however I'm not seeing a change in the behavior.

Comment: I made the change, but it seems to not have made a difference.

Comment: Can you post the updated web.config code after this change you made

Comment: Updated. I'm starting to wonder if the issue is actually badly formatted XML from my vendor. Would you expect this behavior if they were sending invalid characters in the body of the message?

Answer (score 0):

WCF works well over SOAP web service when we use the default configuration, namely the way to call the service is valid only when we use service proxy. It is not advisable to send SOAP information (XML documents) and communicate with the service on the server-side. Thereby I suspect there is something wrong with the invocation to the service.
In your above description, I did not see the way to call the service and the service endpoint. Please pay attention to this line code.

```
[WebInvoke(Method ="POST", UriTemplate = "xml")]
```

This does not make sense since SOAP web service is routed by SOAPAction field in the HTTP request.

> SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"

[image]
The service address merely is the base address, **http://myip:port/service1.svc**

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: The change was requested by our vendor. They kept telling us the "namespace" needs to be an empty string. When we made that change, the test xml they gave us worked in SOAP UI. They've never been able to successfully call our endpoint. Originally, I used all default settings, and everything was good (except for their test xml). Assume that I have no power to modify the incoming request, that there is an error (most likely in the envelope), and I am trying to identify that error.

Answer (score 0):

So the vendor finally sent me a copy of what they are sending me.......

The issue is that they are sending XML expecting a RESTful API. Be aware that for about 12 months they insisted it was a SOAP endpoint they needed. Even now they are calling it SOAP. They kept referring to the options as HTTPS POST or SOAP. They told me they don't offer RESTful.

Thanks for all of your inputs. Here's a pic of how I feel about this whole situation (see attached)

[Angry Dilbert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gtzT.jpg)